# A single word for "very steep", in reference to hiking

Tags: synonyms

Is there a single word that can be used instead of **very steep** when talking about hiking? E.g.

> The last part of the hiking trail was very steep.

**Sheer** might fit but it seems to refer more to a straight cliff than a steep trail.

Comment: What did your dictionaries, thesauruses and search engines leave unclear?

Comment: My thesaurus only listed steep, not very steep. Some searching online gave me the answer below and I thought it might be useful for others as it was not the most apparent answer when searching online; many of the synonyms for steep are not applicable when used in the context of referring to a hiking trail.

Answer (score 1):

**Precipitous** — meaning very steep — is fitting to use when referring to a trail or road that has an exceptionally steep angle. E.g.

> The road up the mountain is precipitous.

Comment: Almost so, logically. I suggest you can't find any significant example of "precipitous"going upwards…